# Tracking errors using XSLT and cURL

Tags: php, xml, xslt

This is my first attempt to perform a transform on an xml returned from cURL in the form of a string. I have a php that I think is written properly as I can at least echo back the string contained in `$xml_data` . However, whenever I attempt to view the php through a browser I get a blank page (and source). What am I doing wrong? Any pointers would be helpful and appreciated..

php

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("http://somewhere.com/deliver_xml.php?release_week=20140126");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$xml_data=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xml->$xml_data;

$xslDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xslDoc->load("new_releases.xsl");

$proc = new XSLTProcessor();
$proc->importStylesheet($xslDoc);

$xmlDoc->loadXML($xml_data);

echo $proc->transformToXML($xmlDoc);

$proc->setParameter('', 'albumid', $_POST["id"]);

?>
```

The XSL (note this is not complete, at this point I'm just attempting to get some of the data from xml on the screen and style it)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

   <xsl:output method="html" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <html><body>
     <div style="position: relative; font-weight: bold; font-size: 24pt;">
        New music for the week of <xsl:value-of select="release_week_start"/></div>
      <xsl:for-each select="/album">
              <a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                href="{../@id}.xhtml">
                <xsl:value-of select="album/artist"/>
              </a>
      </xsl:for-each>        
 </body></html>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If I include echo `$xml_data` in my php I get the following xml string

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<new_release>
 <release_week_start date="January 26, 2014">
  <album id="AD1" albumart="http://peachfields.com/hvcc/ciss227/images/no_art.png">
   <artist>After The Disco</artist>
   <name>Broken Bells</name>
   <year>2014</year>
   <release_date>January 31, 2014</release_date>
   <label>Columbia Records</label>
   <disc>1</disc>
   <totaldiscs>1</totaldiscs>
   <tracklist>
     <track id="1">Perfect World</track>
     <track id="2">After The Disco</track>
     <track id="3">Holding On For Life</track>
     <track id="4">Leave It Alone</track>
     <track id="5">The Changing Lights</track>
     <track id="6">Control</track>
     <track id="7">Lazy Wonderland</track>
     <track id="8">Medicine</track>
     <track id="9">No Matter What You're Told</track>
     <track id="10">The Angel And The Fool</track>
     <track id="11">The Remains of Rock And Roll</track>
   </tracklist>
  </album>
  <album id="CC1" albumart="http://peachfields.com/hvcc/ciss227/images/no_art.png">
   <artist>Casting Crowns</artist>
   <name>Thrive</name>
   <year>2014</year>
   <release_date>January 28, 2014</release_date>
   <label>Reunion Records</label>
   <disc>1</disc>
   <totaldiscs>1</totaldiscs>
   <tracklist>
     <track id="1">Thrive</track>
     <track id="2">All You've Ever Wanted</track>
     <track id="3">Just Be Held</track>
     <track id="4">You Are The Only One</track>
     <track id="5">Broken Together</track>
     <track id="6">Love You With The Truth</track>
     <track id="7">This Is Now</track>
     <track id="8">Dream For You</track>
     <track id="9">Follow Me</track>
     <track id="10">Heroes</track>
     <track id="11">House Of Their Dreams</track>
     <track id="12">Waiting On The Night To Fall</track>
    </tracklist>
   </album>
 </release_week_start>
</new_release>
```

Comment: Okay so sounds like you are getting the XML correctly, I'm thinking the error then is with your transform. try `var_dump ($proc->transformToXML($xmlDoc);)` To see if its actually returning null. If it doesn't print anything on the browser, then you have a fatal error somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @RobMullins I tried what you suggested and it printed out `bool(false)` , So I'm assuming my xsl is not written properly?

Comment: Hard to say for sure, but `transformToXML($xmlDoc)` returns false on error. Insert this after your transform: `print_r(libxml_get_errors())`, it should give you detailed error info.

Comment: I just noticed I forgot to use `</xsl:template>` to close off the template  (kind of embarrassing!). it now prints out my html string  `New music for the week of "` (a literal double quote mark)

Comment: Yup, I just ran a test on it and returned: `[Fatal Error] xsl.xslt:19:3: The element type "xsl:template" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</xsl:template>".`

Comment: If I've set my xsl: output directive to "HTML", do I still need to include the <html> and <body> opening and closing tags or does the xsl take care of those?

Comment: Yes you still need to include all html tags within the xsl template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.transformtoxml.php

Use `libxml_get_last_error()` or `libxml_get_errors()` to retrieve errors in transformations.